# Is there any way a single widget to be added like a showMenu content instead of using property ` items:` which expect `List<PopupMenuEntry<Widget>>`

Tags: flutter

```
showMenu<Widget>(
              context: context,
              color: Colors.white,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5)),
              items: _buildPopupMenuItems(context));
```

Something like `body` property that expects single widget?

Comment: Can you be more specific. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to  add only one widget into the menu and not use `items` and list of Menu items. I am asking for alternative Widget to do the same job. @delmin

Comment: if you want single item add PopupMenuItem. I also don't really understand what are you trying to do and what your outcome suppose to be

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're asking?

```
onPressed: () => showMenu(
        context: context,
        position: RelativeRect.fromLTRB(70.0, 450.0, 100.0, 100.0),
        items: [
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Text('Item'),
          )
        ]),
```

Outcome

[image]